# How to Stop the Webview video in android

Tags: java, android, android-webview

In my project using webview loading the video url using iframe concept ,but call the next inten cannot stop the playing sound or pause the video. or any other coding for loding the video in webview

my code :

```
public class Webviewfullscreen extends Activity {

    WebView webview;
    LinearLayout webViewPlaceholder;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webviewfull);
        webViewPlaceholder=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.webViewholder);
        String VideoUrl=this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webViewDisplay(VideoUrl, webview);
    }
    private void webViewDisplay(final String weburl, final WebView www) {
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void run() {

                WebSettings settings = www.getSettings();
                String Url = "<html> <head> <style type=text/css> iframe {height:100%;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:scroll;} body {background-color:#000; margin:0;}</style> </head> <body> <iframe width=240px height=220px src="
                        + weburl
                        + " frameborder=0 webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></body></html>";

                settings.setLightTouchEnabled(true);

                www.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
                    www.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    www.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
                }
                www.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

                www.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, Url, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            // do something on back.
            System.out.println("on finish");
            webViewPlaceholder.removeView(webview);
            webview.loadUrl("");
            webview.removeAllViews();
            webview.destroy();

            webview = null;
            finish();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Please help how to stop the video

Comment: Why don't you use a VideoView?

Comment: @Enrichman because sometimes WebView is preferred.

Answer (score 6):

It's a little hacky, but if you want to have a pause/play of the video when your activity goes off/on, use this in your Activity:

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    toggleWebViewState(true);
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    toggleWebViewState(false);
}

private void toggleWebViewState(boolean pause)
{           
    try
    {
        Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView")
        .getMethod(pause
                ? "onPause"
                : "onResume", (Class[]) null)
        .invoke(webview, (Object[]) null);
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After spending lot of time i got the conclusion to **pause the video** which is playing with WebView iframe concept of HTML.

Just override the onPause() method on Activity or Fragment, where ever you used webView and call the WebView onPause() method. It works for me.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mWebView.onPause();
}
```

Posting this answer to late but it may help other's.

Comment: What is your application minSdkVersion?? It is working for me for minSdk=14.

Answer (score 1):

In `onPause()` method , set webview to a blank url like below.

```
webview.loadurl("");
```

and it works for me , just try it.